# how to retrieve a promise from an async function inside another async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, request

I am making a post request inside the async function `getAuthToken()` and I am trying to receive the promise in the variable authToken using the await keyword, but for some reason, the await does not work in the way I want it to as `console.log(authToken)` gives undefined. The body inside `getAuthToken()` however `console.logs` the value I need after a couple of seconds.

```
export function authenticateWithLocalStrategy(req, res, next, browserLng) {
return passport.perform().authenticate("local", { session: false }, function(error, user) {
    // Throw exception if loading passport strategy fails
    if (error) {
        return res
            .status(403)
            .send(new ServerResponseError(403, t("validation.userInvalidProperties", { lng: browserLng }), { emailAddress: [t("validation.incorrectLoginDetailsSupplied", { lng: browserLng })] }));
    }
    // Authenticate user with strategy
    req.logIn(user, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            return res
                .status(403)
                .send(
                    new ServerResponseError(403, t("validation.userInvalidProperties", { lng: browserLng }), { emailAddress: [t("validation.incorrectLoginDetailsSupplied", { lng: browserLng })] })
                );
        }
        if (user) {
            database().transaction(async function(transaction) {
                try {
                    // Get current server time
                    const currentTime = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

                    // Load user from database
                    const userObject = await models().user.findOne({ where: { id: user.userId, clientId: user.clientId, active: true } }, { transaction: transaction });
                    
                  //Async await call to retrieve data from post request
                    var authToken = await getauthToken(userObject.firstName, userObject.password);
            
                    console.log(authToken);//this gives undefined
                    // Throw an error if user could not be loaded from database
                    if (userObject === null) {
                        return res.status(403).send(
                            new ServerResponseError(403, t("validation.userInvalidProperties", { lng: browserLng }), {
                                emailAddress: [t("validation.incorrectLoginDetailsSupplied", { lng: browserLng })]
                            })
                        );
                    }

                    // Store lastLoginDate in database
                    userObject.update({
                        lastLoginDate: currentTime,
                        
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    throw error;
                }
            });

            // Build our response object
            const response = { status: 200, message: t("label.success", { lng: browserLng }), token: user.token, keepSignedIn: req.body.keepSignedIn };

            // Return the response object
            return res.status(200).send(response);
        } else {
            const errorMsg = new ServerResponseError(403, t("validation.userInvalidProperties", { lng: browserLng }), {
                emailAddress: [t("validation.incorrectLoginDetailsSupplied", { lng: browserLng })]
            });
            return res.status(403).send(errorMsg);
        }
    });
})(req, res, next);
}

async function getauthToken(username,password){

 var data=“”;
  request.post({
    url:"http://35.232.47.147:8008/token",
    json:{
        username:username,
        password:password
    },
    headers:{
        "Content-type":"application/json"
    }
},
(err,{body})=>{
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(body) //this gives me the value after a few seconds.
    data= body;
});
  return data.
 }
```

Comment: You aren't _returning_ anything from the `getauthToken` function, so the promise returned by the `getauthToken` fulfils with the value of `undefined`. You need to _return_ the result of `request.post(...)` and don't need to pass the callback function to `request.post(...)` if you are going to use the `async-await` syntax.

Comment: Which `request` module are you using? Hopefully not this [deprecated one](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)?

Comment: do you have an alternative solution?

Comment: The issue is not with request. I even tried axios.post() but authToken = await getAuthToken() is not working. It does not wait for the promise to get resolved.

Comment: Reason is explained in the first comment.

Comment: @Yousaf yeah i tried what you said in the first comment but it still doesn't work. It does not wait for the the promise to be resolved

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you changed `getAuthToken` function?

Comment: Your updated `getAuthToken` function won't work because `return data` statement will execute _before_ HTTP request completes and the callback is invoked. Change your function as shown [here](https://pastebin.com/cYfcTk5n). Keep in mind that this assumes that `request.post(...)` returns a `Promise`. If `request` package doesn't provides a promise-based API, consider using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230142/discussion-between-mathew-pius-and-yousaf).